# More options in contextual tag hovermenu

Tags: feature-request

It would be really nice to have options such as `+fav tag` or `ignore tag` when hovering over tags.

The alternative seems to be to go to profile -> prefs -> type in tag character-for-character -> remember to click "Add"... every time you have a new tag you wish to ignore.

Comment: You can click on the star to make it a favorite.

Comment: That feature is *definitely* not discoverable. =(

Comment: +1 Came here to post this feature request. Glad to see someone already did it.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe , clicking on the star won´t favorite the tag related to that question.